# docker-compose recreates a running container despite having a different container_name in the docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  app: 
    build: .
    image: team/repo:$VERSION
    ports:
      - "$PORT:3000" 
    container_name: myname-$VERSION
    volumes: 
      - $DB_PATH:/db
      - ./tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      DB_PATH: /db
volumes:
  db:
  tmp:
```

After I define e.g. `VERSION=1.0.0` and `PORT=80`, I start the container with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

And it creates a container "myname-1.0.0". Afterwards, if I re-export my `env. var`. e.g. `VERSION=1.0.1` and `PORT=8080` and rerun the command, it stops the running container and launches the new one "byname-1.0.1". But the message is:

> Recreating myname-1.0.0 ... done

"docker ps" shows only the new container "myname-1.0.1", but I would expect to see both containers running on ports `80` and `8080`, respectively; and from 2 different images "team/repo:1.0.0" and "team/repo:1.0.1", respectively.

What are the correct steps to have the 2 containers running side by side? I'd appreciate any pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Compose uses labels on containers to remember which container goes with which compose file.  The container names as such aren't used for this.  (In early versions of `fig` this wasn't true, but [since 2015](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/#130) it has been.)

Compose has the notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host).  This has a couple of impacts.  One is that the project name gets put in the container labels, so versions of the same `docker-compose.yml` deployed under different project names are considered different projects.  Another is that there is a default for `container_name:` based on the project and service name.

So, this should work for you if you:

1. Delete the `container_name:` and let Docker Compose construct a non-conflicting default for you; and
2. Use the [`docker-compose -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) or [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) to explicitly specify the project name.

   ```
   VERSION=1.0.0 PORT=80 COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project-100 \
     docker-compose up
   VERSION=1.0.1 PORT=8080 COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project-101 \
     docker-compose up
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the arg build in your docker-compose like this:

```
services:
  app: 
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - VERSION
    image: team/repo:$VERSION
    ports:
      - "$PORT:3000" 
    container_name: myname-$VERSION
    volumes: 
      - $DB_PATH:/db
      - ./tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      DB_PATH: /db
volumes:
  db:
  tmp:
```

and start it like this :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```